# while using SignalR with Service fabric Asp.net core i am getting $.connection undefined exception

Tags: jquery, asp.net, signalr, signalr-hub, azure-service-fabric

I am using signalR with service fabric asp.net core, but while running project i am getting connection undefined exception. i was searching more links regarding this bug i tried almost all the links, but still i am getting same error. please anyone help me to solve this issue.

My Hub class is:

```
namespace WebApp
{
[HubName("chatHub")]
public class ChatHub : Hub
{

    public void send(string message)
    {

        Clients.All.broadcastMessage(message);

    }

}
}
```

and i configured extension class for adding Appbuilder.MapSignalR().

and my Index.cshtml code is

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js" integrity="sha256-BbhdlvQf/xTY9gja0Dq3HiwQF8LaCRTXxZKRutelT44=" crossorigin="anonymous" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/signalr/jquery.signalr-2.2.1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="~/signalr/hubs" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script>
    $(function () {

           alert($.connection);//here i am getting "undefined"

           var chathub = $.connection.chatHub;

           alert(chathub);

           chathub.clients.broadcastMessage = function (msg) {


            $("#discussion").append("<li>" + msg + "</li>");
        };
        $("#sendmessage").click(function () {
            var text = $("#message").val();
            chathub.server.send(text);

        });

        $.connection.hub.start();
    });

</script>

    <div class="container">
        <input type="text" id="message" />
        <input type="button" id="sendmessage" value="Send" />
        <ul id="discussion"></ul>
    </div>
```

Comment: I think you are getting undefined on this line `alert(chathub);` and not on `alert($.connection)`. Are you sure you are using the correct link to hubs - have you tried using `/signalr/hubs` instead of  `~/signalr/hubs`.

Comment: Have you tried same project but not with Service Fabric, and it runs `Ok`? Just trying to understand where the issue is, and if at all relates to Service Fabric, since that is why I looked at this question. You might get more people to look at the issue if it is not related to Service Fabric.